# Data not populated in Partial view in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Hi all i have a view Page Named Grids and partial View Named History,i want to show the partial view in my grid page,i have the view in my page but History page doesnt have he data populated in it

```
   this is my GridsPage

      <%       
                   var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "ResourceName", rowsPerPage: 3);
                     using (Html.BeginForm())
                     { %>  

                         <%: Html.DropDownList("ResourceName", (SelectList)ViewBag.ResourceName, "--Select Project--")%>
                          <%: Html.ValidationMessage("ResourceName")%>  

                           <%: Html.DropDownList("ResourceID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ResourceID, "--Select Project--")%>
                           <%: Html.ValidationMessage("ResourceID")%> 

                           <%: Html.DropDownList("status", (SelectList)ViewBag.status, "--Select Project--")%>                               
                                <form action="Grids.aspx" method="post">
                                <p>
                                 <input type="submit" value="search" />
                               </p> 
                               </form>                          
                        <div id="grid">
                        <%:grid.GetHtml(
                         tableStyle: "listing-border", headerStyle: "gridhead", footerStyle: "paging", rowStyle: "td-dark", alternatingRowStyle: "td-light",                            
                         columns:grid.Columns(                             
                        grid.Column("ResourceID","Resource ID"),
                        grid.Column("ResourceName","Resource Name"),
                        grid.Column("EmployeEmailID","Employee ID"),
                        grid.Column("status","Status"),
                        grid.Column(
                        header: "",
                        style: "text-align-center",
                        format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ResourceID = item.ResourceID }))
                        ))%>
                        </div>
                        <%} %>

               //Rendering the Partial view here
                        <%:Html.Partial("History") %>
```

this is my Partial view

```
       <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>>" %>                 
               <% foreach (var item in Model)
                  { %>                        
                     <div>
                      <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeName)%>
                     </div>                        
                     <div>
                     <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.Resolution)%>
                     </div>
```

this is my controller for Partial view

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult History()
    {
        var getbugs = GetBugs();
        return View(getbugs);
    }
```

its not going to the action method history..can any one correct me where am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult History()
{
    var getbugs = GetBugs();        
    return PartialView(getbugs);
}
```

and in Your aspx page try this changes

```
       <%:Html.Action("History") %>
```

try this changes in your code

Answer (score 0):

Html.Partial won't call the controller. You need to specify the model in the call:

```
<%: Html.Partial("History", GetBugs()) %>
```

The other option, is RenderAction, which will call the controller, and in fact, the entire runtime (routes, etc):

```
<%: Html.RenderAction("History", "ControllerName"); %>
```

Comment: @simmon Whitehead for your first solution i am geting an error at GetBugs() it doesn't exist in the context

Comment: GetBugs must be a static method and called via the full type name in a view, e.g: YourProject.YourNamespace.YourClass.GetBugs(). Otherwise, use RenderAction instead.

Comment: @Simon... am second method used... am getting error ") expected"

Comment: @Simon..am second method used... am getting error ...The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)' has some invalid